# How to enable org mode and evil mode for untitled buffer when creating a new frame

Tags: org-mode, buffers, frames, major-mode, minor-mode

The code below creates a new frame with an untitled buffer, how to make this buffer default with org-mode and evil-mode?

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-n") 'new-empty-frame)

(defun new-empty-frame ()
  "Create a new frame with a new empty buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer (generate-new-buffer "untitled")))
    (set-buffer-major-mode buffer)
    (display-buffer buffer '(display-buffer-pop-up-frame . nil))))
```

1. `M-x org-mode RET` worked, but how to do it with elisp?
2. `M-x evil-mode RET` didn't even work.

[image: new frame]

The code is from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25792276/5520270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is replace the `set-buffer-major-mode` call which sets the buffer to a default mode (`fundamental` mode in this case) with a couple of calls to set the modes you want.

`org-mode` is a major mode, so you set it by calling the function that implements it, with no arguments, in the buffer whose mode you want to set:

```el
(set-buffer <some buffer>)
(org-mode)
```

`evil-mode` is a global minor mode, which can be enabled or disabled at will, like all minor modes. To enable it, you have to call its function with a positive argument:

```
(evil-mode 1)
```

To disable it, you call the function with a negative argument.

All these things and more can be glimpsed by checking the doc string of the functions: `C-h f org-mode RET` and `C-h f evil-mode RET`. If a function does not behave the way you expect, you probably have a wrong expectation and you can check that by reading its doc string, so `C-h f <function> RET` is something you should do often.

Putting it all together, the result is:

```el
(defun new-empty-frame ()
  "Create a new frame with a new empty buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer (generate-new-buffer "untitled")))
    (set-buffer buffer)
    (org-mode)
    (evil-mode 1)
    (display-buffer buffer '(display-buffer-pop-up-frame . nil))))
```

Only partially tested, since I don't have `evil-mode` installed.

Comment: Awesome! It works pretty well. You explain the solution in detail and provide the guidance to help me in the future. Thank you so much, NickD! :D

Comment: You are welcome!